# How to hide Drawer item in react-navigation 5x?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a Drawer navigation in my app using react-navigation, but I'm having difficult to hide one item.
What I want: create some screens (to navigate inside app), but NOT display those screens in Drawer.
I'm using this doc: (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigator-specific-methods-are-available-in-the-navigators-nested-inside)

But I have two problems: 1) `Root` still being displayed; 2) I can't navigate direct to 'hidden' screen, it says that screen doesn't exist.

This is my current code:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
function Root2() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="NewEditPilot" component={NewEditPilot} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}


const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <SideBar2 {...props} />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="PilotMgnt" component={PilotMgnt} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Root2" component={Root2} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}


export default function App() {


  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Root>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <MyDrawer />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </Root>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

In this case, I'm trying to hidde `NewEditPilot` and `Settings` screens. This is how I was navigating to these screens: `navigation.navigate('NewEditPilot')` (this was working on react-navigation 4x).

Also, this is how I was using (and working!) in react-navigation 4x:

```
// Telas principais
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    PilotMgnt: { screen: PilotMgnt},
    CurRace: { screen: CurRace},
    Settings: { screen: Settings},        
    LogViewScreen: { screen: LogViewScreen},    
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  }
);

// sub-telas
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: { screen: Drawer },    
    NewEditPilot: { screen: NewEditPilot },
    PersonalRank: { screen: PersonalRank },  
    RCharts: { screen: RCharts},
    RChartsArchive: { screen: RChartsArchive},
    Archive: { screen: Archive },
    ArchiveView: { screen: ArchiveView },
    ArchivePersonalRank: { screen: ArchivePersonalRank },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Drawer",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);




export default () =>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Root>
          <AppNavigator />
        </Root>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Sidebar2 component you can chose to create a custom `<DrawerContentScrollView />` which will have `<DrawerItem />`. These `<DrawerItem />` would be those items that you want to be made visible in the drawer. `navigation` prop is passed by default to the drawerContent component. You can use this navigation prop to navigate to a particular screen using `navigation.navigate('Screen_Name')`. Make sure there is a `<Drawer.Screen>` available for the route where you want to navigate.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#providing-a-custom-drawercontent

Answer (score 8):

I just manage to solve this properly, with some help from [this issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2021).

To proper hide an item you should make an function that filters the routes, and pass it to the **drawerContent** prop of **Drawer.Navigator**.

Let's assume that you want to hide the **Login** Screen from your Drawer, but you still want to be able to navigate to it, whenever you want, you should do something like this:

```
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  DrawerContentScrollView,
  DrawerItemList,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    
const CustomDrawerContent = (props) => {
    const { state, ...rest } = props;
    const newState = { ...state };
    newState.routes = newState.routes.filter(
      (item) => item.name !== 'Login',
    );
    
    return (
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList state={newState} {...rest} />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
    );
  };
    
  export default () => (
    <Drawer.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: true,
      }}>
       <Drawer.Screen
         name="Home"
         component={HomeScreen}
         options={{ title: 'Home' }}
       />
        .
        .
        .
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: This is a great solution and very flexible. I also use this as a workaround if I want to hide the bottom tab bar for some screens, I just add that screen to the list of drawer items, hide them filtering out that route and works perfectly!